# leaking this constructor java with netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, constructor, initialization

I'm using customButtons as a container for a load of JButtons. I acquire the buttons via name (but via a configuration file):

```
getComponent("btn1");
```

I've done it this way to have a pretty list of buttons, a simple overview of functions, and a reference to the correct panel "jpt" to have all of the help the compiler gives me.

The order, number and selection of buttons also need to be configurable by non programmers  - and i've found a list of button variable names to work well).

The problem is: Netbeans 7.4 gives me the warning "Leaking this in constructor" (line 9), which is true, because i do. Is there a more correct way to achieve the same result ?

```
public class CustomButtons extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    CustomJPanel jpt;
    HashMap<String, Component> components;

    public CustomButtons (CustomJPanel jpt) {
    this.jpt = jpt;
    initComponents();
    components = getAllComponentsInContainer(this);
}

public Component getComponent(String name) {
    return components.get(name);
}

private HashMap<String, Component> getAllComponentsInContainer(Container root) {
    HashMap<String, Component> comps = new HashMap<>();
    for (Component c : root.getComponents()) {
        comps.put(c.getName(), c);
        if (c instanceof Container) {
            comps.putAll(getAllComponentsInContainer((Container) c));
        }
    }

    return comps;
}
```

Comment: Your class names should start with an uppercase letter - it makes distinguishing classes and variables easier.

Comment: thanks, it's a anonymization artifact, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that `getComponents()` is guaranteed to be initialised by the time you call `getAllComponentsInContainer(this)`, you may not be too concerned about the warning - it is mainly there to warn you about the possibility of your instance not being completely initialised yet.

If you want to avoid the warning, you could change the `getAllComponentsInContainer` to just accept the result of `getComponents()` instead:

```
components = getAllComponents(getComponents());
...
private HashMap<String, Component> getAllComponents(Component[] containerComponents) {
    HashMap<String, Component> comps = new HashMap<>();
    for (Component c : containerComponents) {
        comps.put(c.getName(), c);
        if (c instanceof Container) {
            comps.putAll(getAllComponents((Container) c).getComponents());
        }
    }

    return comps;
}
```

Alternatively you could, for example, add an `initialise` method to your class that needs to be called after the constructor is finished (but this means you risk forgetting to call it somewhere):

```
public void initialise() {
    components = getAllComponents(getComponents());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put implementation of method getAllComponentsInContainer in constructor only and set all instance variables as it is in same class you are author , i can not write exact implementation as not sure what you are doing in initComponents() method.

Comment: initComponents() is the swing/awt framework doing it's thing. An edit was suggested to remove the swing tag, and i did. (i couldn't review/accept the edit because i had edited the post in the interim).

Comment: @user3218163 I am not aware of swing , but the problem you have asked is a general design issue. let me put my answer in other way, i suggest do not call getAllComponentsInContainer() in constructor instead of this write code of this method in constructor. this is feasible solution because you are writing this class code. tell me if its not clear.